# javascriptのMapでget()やset()を使わずプロパティの形で使っても問題ないか

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

現在Chromeのextensionを作っているのですが、データを保存するのにMapを使おうと思っています。
そこでMapのドキュメントなどを読んでみたのですがget()やset()を使う方法ばかりで、detail.intervalのようなプロパティの形で使っている例はありませんでした。しかし実際にコンソールなどで

```
detail = new Map()
detail.interval = 7
alert(detail.interval)
```

のように打つと書き込みや読み込みがちゃんと行われます。
この書き方の方が楽なんですが非公式なのでしょうか？ また、chrome.storageでデータを保存するにあたって適切なのでしょうか？
ご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

いいえ．[MDNに詳しい解説があります](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)が，それはオブジェクトプロパティに代入しているだけであってMapとして使えていません．

```
detail = new Map()
detail.interval = 7
detail.has('interval') // false
detail.get('interval') // undefined
```

---

また，`chrome.storage`で使用できるデータ型は`Map`ではなく`Object`です．

> Primitive values such as numbers will serialize as expected. Values with a typeof "object" and "function" will typically serialize to {}, with the exception of Array (serializes as expected), Date, and Regex (serialize using their String representation).
> [https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#:~:text=Primitive%20values,representation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#:%7E:text=Primitive%20values,representation)

つまりは，その用途であれば単純にオブジェクト初期化子`{}`，あるいは`Object.create(null)`などを利用すればいいでしょう．